# conditional avatar not working - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using [WooCommerce Memberships by SkyVerge](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-memberships/) for a membership plan, I am trying to make a conditional avatar for active and inactive members so that the avatar will be different in terms of their membership status.

Plugin ref: https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-memberships-function-reference/

```
$memberships = wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships( $user_id );

if ( ! empty( $memberships ) ) {
    // Avatar For NON-Members
    function wpb_new_gravatar( $avatar_defaults ) {
        $myavatar                     = 'http://staranddaisy.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/smily_icon_avatar-1.png';
        $avatar_defaults[ $myavatar ] = 'Default Gravatar';
        return $avatar_defaults;
    }
} else {
    // Avatar For ACTIVE Members
    function wpb_new_gravatar( $avatar_defaults ) {
        $myavatar                     = 'https://staranddaisy.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Circle_Design_Membership_Level_GOLD.webp';
        $avatar_defaults[ $myavatar ] = 'Default Gravatar';
        return $avatar_defaults;
    }
}

add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'wpb_new_gravatar' );
```

Comment: Write your if/else inside `function wpb_new_gravatar` and use `wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships` inside the function as well.

Comment: can u plz help me out m new in this, m try from my end but nothing happens

Comment: `add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'wpb_new_gravatar' );
function wpb_new_gravatar( $avatar_defaults ) {
    if ( $uid && wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships( $uid ) ) {
        $myavatar = "https://staranddaisy.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Circle_Design_Membership_Level_GOLD.webp";
        return $myavatar;
    } 
    // if not use default 
    else {
        $myavatar = "http://staranddaisy.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/smily_icon_avatar-1.png";
        return $myavatar;
    }
    $avatar_defaults[ $myavatar ] = 'Default Gravatar';
    return $avatar_defaults;
}`

Comment: its not working

Comment: How is not working? [edit] your question with what you've learned and what error messages you are seeing.